# Integral promotion and operator+=

Tags: c++, integer-promotion

I need to eliminate gcc -Wconversion warnings. For example

```
typedef unsigned short     uint16_t;

uint16_t a = 1;
uint16_t b = 2;
b += a;
```

gives

```
warning: conversion to 'uint16_t {aka short unsigned int}' from 'int' may alter its value [-Wconversion]
     b += a;
     ~~^~~~
```

I can eliminate this by

```
uint16_t a = 1;
uint16_t b = 2;
b = static_cast<uint16_t>(b + a);
```

Is there any way to keep the `operator+=` and eliminate the warning? Thank you.

**EDIT**

I use

> gcc test.cpp -Wconversion

my gcc version is

> gcc.exe (Rev3, Built by MSYS2 project) 7.2.0

Comment: Please don't tag both C and C++, use only the language you're programming in. For semantic details like this there are often differences between C and C++.

Comment: OK, sorry. I removed C. :)

Comment: I added it to my question.

Comment: `typedef unsigned short uint16_t`? Why not `#include <cstdint>`? The latter seems to me more reliable.

Comment: I can't do that.

Comment: Technically the compiler is correct with its warning, even if it might be irrelevant (because the compiler can't know what happens at run-time). I can't really see a solution except turning off `-Wconversion`.

Comment: I can't turn off `-Wconversion` either. If there is no better way I'll go with `b = static_cast<uint16_t>(b + a)`.

Comment: Why can't you turn it off? Is it part of a larger project where some "architect" decided that it must always be used? Even if it will often give more false positives than "real" warnings?

Comment: Yes, this was decided on a higher level.

Comment: @bencemeszaros You should have a conversation with the higher level. This warning is not intended for general use.

Comment: It's a level so high that a simple man like myself is not eligible to talk to someone on that high of a level.

Comment: @bencemeszaros Not with that attitude!

Comment: I fiddled a little bit with your code on godbolt (last stable gcc and clang with `-O3`). It was a bit complicated to get comparable code. (The optimizer was in both cases very clever to keep values in registers and to change the order of statements for making this possible.) Finally, I got the impression that the machine code for your workaround `b = static_cast<uint16_t>(b + a);` is identical to the one for `b += a;`. IMHO, if you cannot drop the `-Wconversion` then your workaround is the 2nd best solution.

Comment: @bencemeszaros You can talk to whoever you like! If concerned, bring it up with your immediate supervisor so they can deal with it. This is a social issue, not a technological one.

Comment: I've had a discussion with the higher levels and this flag will not be enabled. Thank you for your support. Maybe there is hope after all.

Comment: @bencemeszaros Well done on this :) See, sometimes you just need to have a conversation, no matter what "level" you're on

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> I need to eliminate gcc -Wconversion warnings.

You don't say why but this is actually unlikely.

From [the GCC wiki page on this switch](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/NewWconversion):

> **Why isn't Wconversion enabled by -Wall or at least by -Wextra?**
>
> Implicit conversions are very common in C. This tied with the fact that there is no data-flow in front-ends (see next question) results in hard to avoid warnings for perfectly working and valid code. `Wconversion` is designed for a niche of uses (security audits, porting 32 bit code to 64 bit, etc.) where the programmer is willing to accept and workaround invalid warnings. Therefore, it shouldn't be enabled if it is not explicitly requested.

If you don't want it, just turn it off.

Mangling your code with unnecessary casts, making it harder to read and maintain, is the wrong solution.

If your build engineers are insisting on this flag, ask them *why*, and ask them to stop.

Comment: This flag will be not enabled after all. Thank you.

Comment: @bencemeszaros Great news!

Answer (score 0):

You could build your own abstraction to overload the `+=` operator, something like

```
template <typename T>
class myVar {
    public:
    myVar(T var) : val{var} {}
    myVar& operator+=(const myVar& t) { 
        this->val = static_cast<T>(this->val + t.val);
        return *this; 
    }
    T val;
};

int main()
{
    typedef unsigned short     uint16_t;

    myVar<uint16_t> c{3};
    myVar<uint16_t> d{4};
    c += d;
}
```

It still uses a `static_cast`, but you only need to use it once and then reuse it. And you don't need it in your `main`.

IMHO it just adds overhead, but opinions may vary...